# How do I query whether a value that exists in one collection is also a value in another collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have two collections: Toys and Supplier. The Supplier collection has a SupplierId and the Toys collection has a map called 'Supplier' that contains the SupplierId among other values such as the supplier name.

I want to query the suppliers collection, but only return the suppliers that appear in the Toys collection.

Comment: Hello, what did you already try? The documentation is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators. It will be easier for us to help you if you show your code and data model.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries can only filter on value that are present in the documents that they return. There is no way to query a collection based on a value or existence in another collection.

Based on that knowledge, you will have to add some value to each suppliers document that allows you to perform the query.

For example, a common workaround might be to keep a `toyCount` in each document, that you increment/decrement when you write to the `Toys` collection. With such a field in place, the query becomes:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("suppliers").where("toyCount", ">=", 1)
```